# How to change DRF to use a Response from a schema?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to change the Django Rest Framework to use a Response from a schema?

For example, a GET using the standard DRF will output:

```
{
  "count": 0,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": []
}
```

Where I would like it to output

```
{
  "meta_stuff": {
    "License": "MIT"
    },
  "data": []
 }
```

Where `results`=`data` and an `extra` ). Would I need to customise DRF or can a swagger.JSON schema be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're talking about pagination style. If so you should look at this link: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles.

Basically you're going to write your own custom Pagination class, customizing DRF's behavior. Documentation's example is exactly what you've described.